# Remove Values from Hidden Div Forms

Tags: jquery, forms, input, hidden

Is there a way to remove Form input/select values when you hide a div?

Example: Let say i have a form that i fill out. I have a couple different choices, each one will show a different div with a different form and hide the rest. But when i submit, it still submits those form values, even when the div is hidden.

Is it possible to remove all hidden form values?

I prefer jQuery if possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$(divyoujusthid).find(':input').attr('disabled', true);
```

Comment: You can shorten the find to ':input'

Comment: With disabling, there seems to be a problem with IE7.

Instead, i remove the values:

$(':input:hidden').val("");

Answer (score 3):

You could use the [:hidden](http://docs.jquery.com/Selectors/hidden) selector and disable all hidden inputs.

Ex:

```
$(':input:hidden').attr('disabled', true);
```

Edit: changed from null to disabled, simplified selector per suggestion by Chaos

Comment: Suggest also using :input:hidden per Paolo Bergantino's comment to my answer.

Comment: updated... I must say that is awesome! Thanks Paolo and chaos :)

Answer (score 2):

You can iterate through all of the input elements of the hidden div and disable them. Disabled form inputs do not submit anything.